# Keystone vs. Feed-Thru vs. Punchdown Patch Panels

Tags: networking, ethernet, wiring

We have a new office that needs some ethernet wiring done to a cabinet in a closet (no more than 48 cables). There seems to be so many options now. I'd traditionally terminate everything at a rack-mounted 110 style punchdown patch panel, but there is a lot to love about keystone or feed-through patch panels when replacing a single cable.

Is there any reason not to use a feed-through or keystone patch panel?

Answer (score 3):

Do not use pass through. As you ramp up speed, pass through will probably need to be replaced. I have used keystone however prefer a traditional patch panel. I do agree with the comment that keystone lets you create your own color coding but question as to it's value in a small installation.

Whatever the choice, insure the terminations are done to a high quality. NEXT becomes very important if you begin moving to 10G in a few years. We are looking at moving to a 10G backbone soon and some of out cabling is not up to the quality needed.

Answer (score 1):

Really, they'll all perform the same as long as the termination is good.  I say go with what's easiest for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use either, somethings to consider

- cable management
- one less termination
- client office furniture moving
- Appearence
- amount of slack cable in the wall

The price of jacks is about 5.99 which would drive your keystone pass-thru panel to about $300+, Versus a traditional panel at $120

Answer (score 0):

Feed through is a new one to me, but after a quick look I don't think they'd be appropriate in the same applications that keystone or 110 would be.

One additional benefit to keystone is being able to create your own color coding scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I would use traditional patch panels.  I would also put mutiple jacks per room/location and color code them at the oputlet (say blue and white) the blue I would terminate to panel 1 and the white one I would terminate to panel 2 (in the same numbered location).  Personally for panels over 12 ports I use the traditional, for smaller it does not really matter, as many times samller panels tend to be in smaller environments with lower speed requirement.